# How do I get specific colums from an encrypted datatable?

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 files which I open via OpenFileDialog and decrypt them with a method out of my FileGenerator class. In the end i want to compare both datatables via compareTo and fill them into an ultragrid. The problem is that I get a "System.ArgumentException" which says

> Column 'KostenArt' doesn't belong to table

I found out in another post that it probably has something to do with the `FileGenerator.ReadFromProtectedFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)` function. I appreciate any help, thank you!

This is where I get the exception:

```
Private Function ConvertDataTableToListOfISAACService(dt As DataTable, lst As List(Of ISAACService)) As List(Of ISAACService)

    Try
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

            Dim ISAAC As New ISAACService(row(KostenArt).ToString, row(UANR).ToString, row(Ueberbegriff).ToString, row(Benennung).ToString, CDbl(row(Anzahl)), row(Einheit).ToString, CDbl(row(Einzelkosten)), CInt(row(Gesamtmenge)), row(Summencode).ToString)
            lst.Add(ISAAC)
        Next

        Return lst
    Catch ex As System.ArgumentException

    End Try

End Function
```

Here is my MainForm.vb:

```
Public Class MainForm

Private Const KostenArt As String = "KostenArt"
Private Const UANR As String = "UANR"
Private Const Ueberbegriff As String = "Ueberbegriff"
Private Const Benennung As String = "Benennung"
Private Const Anzahl As String = "Anzahl"
Private Const Einheit As String = "Einheit"
Private Const Einzelkosten As String = "Einzelkosten"
Private Const Gesamtmenge As String = "Gesamtmenge"
Private Const Summencode As String = "Summencode"

Public dt1, dt2 As DataTable
Public lst1, lst2 As New List(Of ISAACService)

Private Sub btnDatei1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDatei1.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        If File.Exists(OpenFileDialog1.FileName) Then
            dt1 = FileGenerator.ReadFromProtectedFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            dgv1.DataSource = dt1
            ConvertDataTableToListOfISAACService(dt1, lst1)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnVergleich_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnVergleich.Click
    CompareDataTables()
End Sub


Private Sub btnDatei2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDatei2.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        dt2 = FileGenerator.ReadFromProtectedFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        dgv2.DataSource = dt2
        ConvertDataTableToListOfISAACService(dt2, lst2)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CompareDataTables()
    'Beide Listen durchlaufen und vergleichen
    For Each item1 As ISAACService In lst1
        For Each item2 As ISAACService In lst2
            item1.CompareTo(item2)
        Next
    Next

End Sub

Private Function ConvertDataTableToListOfISAACService(dt As DataTable, lst As List(Of ISAACService)) As List(Of ISAACService)

    Try
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

            Dim ISAAC As New ISAACService(row(KostenArt).ToString, row(UANR).ToString, row(Ueberbegriff).ToString, row(Benennung).ToString, CDbl(row(Anzahl)), row(Einheit).ToString, CDbl(row(Einzelkosten)), CInt(row(Gesamtmenge)), row(Summencode).ToString)
            lst.Add(ISAAC)
        Next

        Return lst
    Catch ex As System.ArgumentException

    End Try

End Function

End Class
```

Here is the `FileGenerator` function:

```
 Public Shared Function ReadFromProtectedFile(ByVal FileName As String) As DataTable

        Dim Data As New DataTable()

        Dim FirstRow As Boolean = True

        If File.Exists(FileName) Then

            Dim Content As String = File.ReadAllText(FileName)

            Content = Decrypt(Content)

            Dim EndPos = Content.LastIndexOf(RowSeparator, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
            If EndPos > -1 Then
                Content = Content.Substring(0, EndPos)
            End If

            Dim ContentRows As String() = RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(Content, RowSeparator)

            If ContentRows.Count > 0 Then

                For Each ContentRow In ContentRows

                    Dim RowCols As String() = RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(ContentRow, ColSeparator)
                    Dim ColCount = RowCols.Count - 1

                    If FirstRow Then
                        For Counter As Integer = 0 To ColCount

                            Dim ColDef() As String = RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(RowCols(Counter), TypeSeparator)

                            Dim myCol As New DataColumn()
                            myCol.ColumnName = ColDef(0)

                            If ColDef.Length > 1 Then
                                myCol.DataType = Type.GetType(ColDef(1))
                            Else
                                'General.Log("STILL OLD FILEFORMAT FOR " & FileName) 'MLHIDE
                                'TODO: Später nur noch nach neuem Format erlauben
                                'Typ nach altem Prinzip holen
                                Select Case Counter
                                    Case 4, 8, 10
                                        myCol.DataType = GetType(Integer)
                                    Case 6
                                        myCol.DataType = GetType(Double)
                                    Case Else
                                        myCol.DataType = GetType(String)
                                End Select
                            End If

                            Data.Columns.Add(myCol)
                        Next
                        FirstRow = False
                    Else

                        Dim myRow As DataRow = Data.NewRow()

                        For i As Integer = 0 To ColCount
                            If Data.Columns(i).DataType Is GetType(Double) Or Data.Columns(i).DataType Is GetType(Double) Then
                                Dim Val As Double = 0
                                Double.TryParse(RowCols(i), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), Val)
                                myRow.Item(i) = Val 'Double.Parse(RowCols(i), EN) 'MLHIDE
                            Else
                                If Data.Columns(i).DataType Is GetType(DateTime) Then
                                    myRow.Item(i) = DateTime.Parse(RowCols(i), CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")) 'MLHIDE
                                Else
                                    myRow.Item(i) = RowCols(i)
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next

                        Data.Rows.Add(myRow)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If

        Return Data

    End Function
```

And here is the ISAACServiceBase class with all the properties(specific colums i want from the file) and the constructor:

```
    Public MustInherit Class ISAACServiceBase


    ReadOnly Property KostenArt As String
    ReadOnly Property UANR As String
    ReadOnly Property Ueberbegriff As String
    ReadOnly Property Benennung As String
    ReadOnly Property Anzahl As Double
    ReadOnly Property Einheit As String
    ReadOnly Property Einzelkosten As Double
    ReadOnly Property Gesamtmenge As Integer
    ReadOnly Property Summencode As String

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(kostenArt As String, uanr As String, ueberbegriff As String, benennung As String, anzahl As Double, einheit As String, einzelkosten As Double, gesamtmenge As Integer, sumcode As String)
        Me.KostenArt = kostenArt
        Me.UANR = uanr
        Me.Ueberbegriff = ueberbegriff
        Me.Benennung = benennung
        Me.Anzahl = anzahl
        Me.Einheit = einheit
        Me.Einzelkosten = einzelkosten
        Me.Gesamtmenge = gesamtmenge
        Me.Summencode = sumcode
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Couple questions.  1) Is Content = Decrypt(Content) producing the expected result?  After decryption what exactly is the Content?  Is it a CSV file maybe?  If so there are a number of external tools available via nugets that will simplify converting it to a DT.  Even if some other standard(ish) file format, might still have some luck

Comment: @Hursey The FileGenerator is legacy code and i don't know what the expected result is. I was told that it works. " Content = Decrypt(Content) has a huge string as value when debugging. How can i check if it is a CSV file?

Comment: Is the file passed as FileName a valid text file? Can you open it in Notepad?

Comment: In the ReadFromProtectedFile your doing multiple splits based on various separators.  What are they? and if this is working, what is the structure of the returned datatable?  Does that match your expectations?

Comment: What does Content look like in Notepad? Can you show a sample?

Comment: @Hursey No the returned DataTable doesnt match my expectations. It got columns i dont need in the comparison

Comment: Extra columns probably don't matter.  Is the KostenArt column there (And all others your trying to access) Are you able to drop a screenshot of the data visualizer for Data?

Comment: @Mary i can open it in notepad and it looks like this, just way longer: 1BDnafY7YUSw6bdR5d9Cj5n0WoZCk+1eI3m8jklopclV/fyZx4STzmPd4kHEGKQpX3hj8qOL885vzFp+Jmb4ptwva1PvqNdN0IIsYIVNFSn/uoC6/mr6TIcX+6vM/BZQXz+tD1fIaiAnpXjRF0k1uYx3E8BEeB30svAUt/vZG1VY24lTn3os/aGr1LCL7gM8sFURbmNCjVLn//DMz+aqGibJZOuzzzuxpm+G7tBwPUulCKeg46rMKh71yb49++5Tpb7bjAxcD4Pmh+GjG07TpCYzGFeCCBld4xh9GOuglGDZD0uliIjDBTI4w+nJLjtbhSv88M01NUjFviGEiCSZKC6brxXBkM6fJLA5sSxCM82Ox7h4U2edyhhP3hG54Rvhlw0Hk/AlqsU1WH89AqxNcXjWausmEFDi4pbLHVd/T6WOxvmbVjgaWRXLvPojRlo/Znvue1op82Gkxz/4xGUP0xmGShtefLvUel

Comment: Great! Now show Content in notepad.

Comment: @Hursey https://imgur.com/a/tZ7ovxo

Comment: @Mary Content wont open in Notepad

Comment: And their I think the problem is.  Bit of a guess here, that result has a column K_Art, and looks like your looking for KostenArt.  If you change Private Const KostenArt As String = "KostenArt" to Private Const KostenArt As String = "K_Art" what happens?

Comment: I think we need to see the Encrypt code. Is there an Imports to tell us what library you are using? There is a Decrypt in System.IO. There would be lots of approaches.

Comment: Thats good to hear progress at least.  So, you DVG is bound to a datatable with the K_Art column, suspect you've created the columns by hand via the designer, that column likely still looking for the "KostenArt" field in the data table.  You probably need to just update that

Comment: @Hursey Yes, i already figured it out via the designer, thank you. Thank you too, Mary.